# How to add a class in wp_nav_menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new on WordPress and i don't know how to add any class in wp_nav_menu so if anybody who help me .

```php
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary',
'menu'=>'Menu','container'=>'','items_wrap'=>'<ul  class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help. in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php there is a function wp_nav_menu( $args = array() ) where the menu is creted. In the functions there is the $deafults array which loock like this:

```
$defaults = array( 
    'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 
    'container_class' => '', 
    'container_id' => '', 
    'menu_class' => 'menu', 
    'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before' => '', 'after' => '', 
    'link_before' => '', 
    'link_after' => '', 
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0,
    'walker' => '', 
    'theme_location' => '' );
```

change 'menu_class' => 'menu' to 'menu_class' => 'menu my_class'